# Illegal hardware instruction when co_awaiting inside if statement

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

Hello I've encountered quite interesting behavior when I was working with my code that is using boost coroutines. I'm talking about Boost Coroutine TS that uses C++20 features, not Boost's implementation of Coroutines either stackless or stackful version that was developed using macros etc, I'm talking about C++20 version.

Anyways, it seems that when I co_await some expression directly in if statement, due to some not-yet understandable to me reasons the code execution breaks with information that something has triggered: "illegal hardware instruction". I guess that it has something to do with the bool conversion of "something" that was immediately returned when the function was co_awaited. It's definitely not the explicit value that the function returns but something that is hidden at the first glance, I guess that this "something" is boost::awaitable object. But it's still unclear to me what (and why) actually triggers such behavior.

Below is the code, that should reproduce the behavior I experienced.

Edit:
I'm using GCC 11.2

```
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::awaitable<bool> get_result()
{
  auto executor = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
  auto timer = boost::asio::steady_timer{executor};
  timer.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(5));
  
  co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable);

  co_return true;
}


boost::asio::awaitable<void> run()
{

  //Working version
  //  const auto result = co_await get_result();
  //  if (result) {
  //    std::cout << "Got result!\n";
  //  }

  //Working version
  // if (auto result = co_await get_result(); result) {
  //   std::cout << "Got result\n";
  // }

  // Not working version
  if (co_await get_result()) {
    std::cout << "Got result!\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  auto bctx = boost::asio::io_context{};
  boost::asio::co_spawn(bctx, run(), boost::asio::detached);
  bctx.run();
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Clang will emit `UD2` instead of `ret` if you forget to put a return statement in a non-void function.

Comment: I'm using GCC 11.2